# Search for Word in Text file and replace with value from dictionary, only once

Tags: python

I want to take a file and make replacements of text taken from values in a dictionary. My issue that I'm running into is that I only want it to run through and make the replacements in the text once. I know there are a couple ways to do "find and replace" within a text file, but I can't seem to get around this issue I'm having.

If the text file is:

```
TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
 config1
TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
 config2
TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3
 config3
```

The issue is that I replace "TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1" with "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3", but it gets changed again once I get to the next value in the dictionary. I need it to be only replaced once, but I can't see a way to do this. You'll see the result at the bottom.

```
from re import sub

#Based on dict, replaces key with the value on the target
def replace_content(dict_replace, target):
    for check, replacer in list(dict_replace.items()):
        target = sub(check, replacer, target)
    return target

dict_replace = {
    "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1": "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3",
    "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2": "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1",
    "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3": "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2"
}

file_open = open('textold.txt', 'r')
file_read = file_open.read()
file_open.close()

new_file_open = open('new_file.txt', 'w')
new_content = replace_content(dict_replace, file_read)
new_file_open.write(new_content)
new_file_open.close()

# Test
print("Old Text: ")
print(file_read)
print("New Content 1: ")
print(new_content)
```

The result I get is:

```
Old Text: 
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
 config 1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
 config 2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3
 config 3

New Content 1: 
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
 config 1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
 config 2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
 config 3
```

Comment: add the expected output

Comment: Create a `set` of words that have been replaced, but check if first to see if the is already in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
from re import sub

dict_replace = {
    "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1": "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3",
    "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2": "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1",
    "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3": "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2"
}

new_file = []
with open('textold.txt', 'r') as read_file:
    for line in read_file: 
        clean_line = line.strip() # Removes \n to make proper comparison
        if clean_line in dict_replace:
            new_file.append(dict_replace[clean_line] + '\n')
        else: 
            new_file.append(line)

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as write_file: 
    for line in new_file: 
        write_file.write(line)
```

As some general advice, it is better to avoid explicitly opening and closing resources such as files and databases like this:

`file_open = open('textold.txt', 'r')` and `file_open.close()`

It is usually better to use [context managers](https://dbader.org/blog/python-context-managers-and-with-statement), because they ensure that resources are closed automatically after leaving the context of the `with` statement.

`with open('textold.txt', 'r') as read_file:`

Comment: Very clean solution! Got this plugged into my code and it works great.

Comment: @jread - Do keep in mind, if you have anything else in a line, this approach will not replace the text (may not matter in your use case). Example this will convert properly `interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1`, but this will not `ainterface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea. You can specify an intermediate hash (or some other unique value) to replace values, then replace the hashes at the end.

Working example

```py
from re import sub
from uuid import uuid4

# Based on dict, replaces key with the value on the target


def _replace_content(to_h, target):
    for check, replacer in to_h.items():
        target = sub(check, replacer, target)
    return target

def replace_content(to_h, h_lookup, target):
    target = _replace_content(to_h, target)
    for h, final_out in h_lookup.items():
        target = sub(h, final_out, target)
    return target


dict_replace = {
    "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1": "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3",
    "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2": "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1",
    "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3": "interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2"
}

to_hash = {}
intermediate_hash_lookup = {}
for check, replace in dict_replace.items():
    intermediate_hash = str(uuid4())
    intermediate_hash_lookup[intermediate_hash] = replace
    to_hash[check] = intermediate_hash

file_read = """interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
 config 1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
 config 2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3
 config 3"""

new_content = replace_content(to_hash, intermediate_hash_lookup, file_read)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Test
    print("Old Text: ")
    print(file_read)
    print()
    print("New Content 1: ")
    print(new_content)
```

**Output**

```sh
Old Text: 
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
 config 1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
 config 2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3
 config 3

New Content 1: 
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3
 config 1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
 config 2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
 config 3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This did it! I was attempting to do something similar (adding in some special characters along with replacement) but ran into issues. Thanks for the quick answer on something so critical to my project here. @Bobs-Burgers

Comment: @jread - No problem. I've worked with these types of scenarios before. Good luck on the project!